# How does Hadoop decides which mapper to run in MapTask class, OldMapper or NewMapper?

Tags: reflection, hadoop, mapreduce

I cannot understand the difference between `runOldMapper(...)` and `runNewMapper(...)` methods in `MapTask` class. Hadoop decides based on `"useNewApi"` parameter from `JobConf`; but where and when in the framework this parameter has been set? I think the default value is FALSE for all jobs. We can set the value to TRUE by calling `JobConf.setUseNewMapper(boolean flag)` which sets `"mapred.mapper.new-api"`, but when and why we should decide to set this parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in the assumption that this behaviour is triggered by the `mapred.mapper.new-api` configuration.

Depending on whether your using the new or old job conf/client, look in the source for:

- `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit()` method, which calls the `setUseNewAPI()` private method. This configures the `new-api` properties depending on whether the old mapper / reducer class properties are set or not
- `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf` - As you note in your question, you the developer will need to call the `setUseNewMapper(true)` method if you are using a new API mapper implementation (false by default and your mapper class implements the mapred.Mapper interface, or true if your mapper extends the mapreduce.Mapper class)

Comment: tahnks for your information Chris. but what is the difference between **mapred.Mapper** and **mapreduce.Mapper** class? are they for different reasons?

Comment: They are more or less comparable - mapred package is known as the 'old' API, mapreduce is the 'new' API (the new API feels cleaner). Both have their own input and output formats (the old api uses an OutputCollector and Reporter objects, while the new api uses Context). I guess it depends on what version of hadoop you are using, but i would certainly recommend using the new api (mapreduce) if you're starting out.

Comment: I am using hadoop 1.0.3 (the stable version when I started) to provide some MPI communication APIs between Jvms (Map tasks).

Comment: Just another question Chris. When the Task Tracker launches a new Jvm for running child maps/reduces, it provides TaskUmbilical Interface for the child as a RPC service. I have another interface on the Task Tracker named Example Interface. Can I bind it to the same port on the Task Tracker for RPC communications? i.e can I bind both Task Umbilical and Example interfaces to the same port on the Task Tracker or I have to bind them to two different ports? - The purpose of Example Interface it to provide some MPI functions for child processs.

Comment: I'm not sure - you'd have to look through the source and make amendments in the TaskTracker and other related classes